# How to "undo" a Projection in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, projection, icriteria

I have to display some objects which are stored in a relational database and I use fluent NHibernate to get them.

Since I need paging, I have to get both - the count of all objects, and the objects for the current page themselves.

The ICriteria for both purposes is very similar up to a point - for count i finally add
*.SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())*
and for current object list I add
*SetFirstResult, AddOrder* and *SetMaxResults*

Is there any way I could undo the projection on the criteria and reuse criteria for the results themselves, or do I have to reconstruct the criteria  for that purpose?

[hibernate forums](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=959525&view=next) suggests a way that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a method encapsulating the query logic including restrictions, grouping, ...:

```
public DetachedCriteria GetCriteria()
{
    return DetachedCriteria.For<Entity>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq(...))
        .Add(...);
}
```

And then send requests to the database:

```
var count = GetCriteria()
    .GetExecutableCriteria(session)
    .SetProjection(Projections.Count(Projections.Id()))
    .UniqueResult<int>();

var result = GetCriteria()
    .GetExecutableCriteria(session)
    .SetFirstResult(0) 
    .SetMaxResults(10)
    .List<Entity>();
```

To further optimize this you could take a look at this excellent blog [post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/27/nhibernate-futures.aspx) in which Ayende Rahien talks about NHibernate Futures.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static DetachedCriteria Clone(this DetachedCriteria criteria)
{
   var dummy = criteria.ToByteArray();
   return dummy.FromByteArray<DetachedCriteria>();
}
```

> ```
> var criteria = GetCriteria()
> var count = criteria 
>     .Clone()
>     .GetExecutableCriteria(session)
>     .SetProjection(Projections.Count(Projections.Id()))
>     .UniqueResult<int>();
>
> var result = criteria 
>     .GetExecutableCriteria(session)
>     .SetFirstResult(0) 
>     .SetMaxResults(10)
>     .List<Entity>();
> ```

Comment: ICriteria implements IClonable now, so you can just call the Clone method that's already implemented.